# I need to place the text near by their figure/table citation. My actual text placed at end of document. How to achieve using perl?

Tags: perl

```
%%Figure-9
\begin{figure}[t]
\figurebox{}{}{1}[fgene-10-00561-g009]
\caption{Ectopic expression of \textit{TaPP2C135} in 
\textit{Arabidopsis}. \textbf{(A)}~Expression levels of}
\end{figure}
```

Need to place the above figure text near to citation end of paragraph, Citation would be in text ".... (\hyperref[F9]{\textbf{Figure~9}})."

Kindly help genius, i am the beginner!

Answer (score 1):

In tex file we couldn't find the end paragraph with a simple logic. Hence I have placed the figure at the end of the figure citation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $texcontent = ' Sample content...
Need to place the above figure text near to citation end of paragraph, Citation would be in text ".... (\hyperref[F9]{\textbf{Figure~1}})."

Need to place the above figure text near to citation end of paragraph, Citation would be in text ".... (\hyperref[F9]{\textbf{Figure~2}})."

Need to place the above figure text near to citation end of paragraph, Citation would be in text ".... (\hyperref[F9]{\textbf{Figure~9}})."

Need to place the above figure text near to citation end of paragraph, Citation would be in text ".... (\hyperref[F9]{\textbf{Figure~3}})."

%%Figure-1
\begin{figure}[t]
\figurebox{}{}{1}[fgene-10-00561-g009]
\caption{Ectopic expression of \textit{TaPP2C135} in 
\textit{Arabidopsis}. \textbf{(A)}~Expression levels of}
\end{figure}

%%Figure-2
\begin{figure}[t]
\figurebox{}{}{1}[fgene-10-00561-g009]
\caption{Ectopic expression of \textit{TaPP2C135} in 
\textit{Arabidopsis}. \textbf{(A)}~Expression levels of}
\end{figure}

%%Figure-3
\begin{figure}[t]
\figurebox{}{}{1}[fgene-10-00561-g009]
\caption{Ectopic expression of \textit{TaPP2C135} in 
\textit{Arabidopsis}. \textbf{(A)}~Expression levels of}
\end{figure}

';

my ($pre,$match,$post) = "";
while($texcontent=~m/\%\%(Figure\-(?:[\w]+))\n?\\begin\{(figure\*?)\}((?:(?!\\end\{\2\}).)*)\\end\{\2\}/gs)
{
    $pre = $pre.$`; $match = $&; $post = $'; (my $figId = $1)=~s/\-/\~/i; #%%Figure-1 replaced with Figure~1

    if($pre=~m/$figId\}\}\)/i) #Searching the ID
    {
        $match=~s/\{figure/\{completedfigure/i; #Completed the figures changed to completedfigures.
        $pre=~s/$figId\}\}\)/$&\n<figplacedhere>$match<figplacedhere>/i; #TAG Placed figures identification 
        $match = "";
    }

    $pre = $pre.$match; $texcontent = $post;
}

if(length $pre) {  $texcontent = $pre.$post;  }

$texcontent=~s/<figplacedhere>//g; $texcontent=~s/\{completedfigure/\{figure/g;

print "--\n$texcontent\n--\n";
```

Purely based on your input I have updated the code unless until the sample input differs might be the code doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you bro. It works great. But i need to replace the text at the end of paragraph instead of near the match. End of paragraph is normal carriage return.

Comment: Please check once again that the *TEX input doesn't end with carriage return multiple lines as a single paragraph and double enter only the split for the paragraph.